# MongoDB - Add object during projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an object as below in the DB:

```
[
  {
    _id: 12,
    name: "access",
    mobileNo: 9153438340
  },
  {
    _id: 13,
    name: "Apple",
    mobileNo: 9153438343
  },
  {
    _id: 14,
    name: "Dell",
    mobileNo: 9153438344
  }
]
```

and I want to add another object during the projection:

```
{
  _id: 15,
  name: "Skype",
  mobileNo: 9153438345
}
```

and the final result would be both objects should be combined as:

```
[
  {
    _id: 12,
    name: "access",
    mobileNo: 9153438340
  },
  {
    _id: 13,
    name: "Apple",
    mobileNo: 9153438343
  },
  {
    _id: 14,
    name: "Dell",
    mobileNo: 9153438344
  }   
  {
    _id: 15,
    name: "Skype",
    mobileNo: 9153438345
  }  
]
```

I tried the below query to get the desired query results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      mobileNo: 1
      // Include other fields from the existing documents as needed
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      combinedResults: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              _id: 15,
              name: "test",
              mobileNo: 9553438343
              // Add other fields to the new object as needed
            }
          ],
          "$$ROOT" // Include the existing documents
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$combinedResults" // Unwind the array to get separate documents
  }
]);
```

But it is not working as expected, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$project`
2. `$group` - Group multiple documents into a single document with `combineResults` array.
3. `$set` - Set `combineResults` array. For your added object, should wrap in an array.
4. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `combineResults` array.
5. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with `combineResults` object.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      mobileNo: 1// Include other fields from the existing documents as needed
      
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      combinedResults: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      combinedResults: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$combinedResults",
          [
            {
              _id: 15,
              name: "test",
              mobileNo: 9553438343// Add other fields to the new object as needed
              
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$combinedResults"// Unwind the array to get separate documents
    
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$combinedResults"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SMC6XzQ0ITr)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, works as expected !!

Comment: Also, I have a $match query  in the above query , if no object is match then also I want to return default values

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AFsLbDUToEL)? Filter the object with the array after `$group` with `$filter` operator. Note that this will not use the indexing as if you place the `$match` stage as first stage, when no document is matched, it will straight return empty result. Maybe you can consider to migrate the logic for adding the default object to back-end instead of working in MongoDB.

Comment: I have huge objects before ```$match``` if I didn't place a ```$match``` in first stage then time complexity will increase.

Comment: Either the add default object logic to be implemented in the back-end as mentioned in the previous comment, or you should use [`$unionWith`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/) operator to join the result with another collection in order to allow the indexing work (by placing the `$match` stage at beginning of the pipeline). This requires you to add another collection and store the default object document. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tc0RQCJOSTs)